# cache or shared class for global variables in aspnet

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, class, caching, shared

cache and shared classes are application wide. there are some details I know but here's scenario:

I'm keeping parameters in database.
I read them to datatable and store them in cache.
whenever I need I directcast cache variable to datatble, query it and get the result.
So I'm not using sql server every time.

Alternative is:
read database and store it in class shared variable
Whenever needed I use this shared variable (datatable) and query it.
if this variable is empty I fill ilt from db.
as variable is datatable I cont need to directcast it.

which one is preferred ? OR can I use any of them as there's no difference.

This class is not a special one. Just contains functions that reads parameters from database. To speed it up I started to use aspnet cache but I noticed that I don't need to because class variables can handle that.

any suggestions ? Can you think any possible outcome for this scenario that only works with parameters that won't change ?

```
    class Class1

       private shared localVar as datatable

       public shared function readParam1 as string  -- this is my old method
          ... SELECT from params table
          return  value
       end function

       public shared function readParam2 as string   -- then I implemented this
          if httpcontext.cache variable is empty then
               ... SELECT from params table
               ... set cache variable
          end if
          value = directcast(cachevalue, string) 
          return  value
       end function  

       public shared function readParam3 as string  -- now I'm planing to use this
          if localVar is empty then
               ... SELECT from params table
               ... slocalVar = sql table
          end if
          value = select value with localVar.Select function 
          return  value
       end function 

end class
```

Comment: I the values won't change I would store them on a shared member, with the sole difference that I would also load the value on applications start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shared variables are the winner here:
1. they would be a little faster than cache because cache needs to lookup dictionary.
2. they are more readable, easier to use

In fact I can't remember use for cache. Because whatever you store in cache is shared data, so? In fact I'm so curoious about this question I'll open new stackoverflow question: [asp.net shared variables vs cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28922456/asp-net-shared-variables-vs-cache)