# asp.net shared variables vs cache

Tags: asp.net, caching

What's the point of asp.net cache when you can save shared info as global variables in shared classes? Because you need to know that variables in user controls get cleared on every postback, but variables in shared classes persist.

Shared variables are better because
1. they would be a little faster than cache because cache needs to lookup dictionary.
2. they are more readable, easier to use

Am I missing something?

Comment: Save some data, let's say from db, for a set period of time (my choice) and only hit said datasource (or external API) when I say so, or if the cache expires and/or is invalidated for some reason.

Comment: I did some research and found out thread safety and memory could be problem (cache can save data to disk if it gets to big i guess). but if variable is small and readonly shared variables are ok. as long as you do lock(SharedVar) (C#) when you are assigning value to your shared variable.

Comment: Just like anything, it's _there_ for one to use _appropriately_. The point is that at the end of the day, they are used differently/for different reasons. "Global" variables (e.g. settings and such) that are ok to persist for the _lifetime of the app_ vs. some _changing_ data that can be persisted based on some other "lifetime" that you can control.